# What's the difference between conversationThread and conversation?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was investigating the documentation and it's not clear for me what exactly is the difference between **conversationThread** and **conversation** on Microsoft Graph (v1.0 Reference)?

The documentation for [conversation](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/conversation) states: *A conversation is a collection of threads, and a thread contains posts to that thread. All threads and posts in a conversation share the same subject.* The relationship is **threads**.
Here I assume that *same subject* means under the umbrella of that conversation?

In another hand, the documentation for [conversationThread](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/conversationthread) states: *A conversationThread is a collection of posts. The last post's recipients collection is the aggregated recipients of the entire thread. A thread can have a growing collection of recipients. A new thread is created when a recipient is removed from the thread.* The relationship is **posts**. Not a clue here, if conversationThread is a collection of posts, that's pretty much the same of what conversation offers?

What I have been trying to do? I'm using Fiddler to play with the HTTP requests `groups/<id>/conversations` and `groups/<id>/threads` and I've noticed that the most obvious difference is that `threads` has a `isLocked` property which `conversations` doesn't. Then the question popped up in my mind: "Why and in which circumstances I'd be using `group/<id>/threads` over `group/<id>/conversations` anyway?". Maybe because I don't understand the difference between **conversationThread** and **conversation**.

Please bare in mind I'm a novice on Microsoft Graph and I'd really appreciate if the community could help me to clarify this question.

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Using Fiddler, we've managed to create a new thread. However, rather than creating a new thread in a specified conversation as expected, it creates a new conversation to go with the new thread. A have also attempted creating a new post within the newly created thread but i am facing the following error: "The OData request is not supported" using the request body: "
`{
  "body": {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "content": "This is a test"
  }
}`"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for your interest and trying out the group conversations API. I'd like to share my understanding with you regarding your few questions:

- "What exactly is the difference between conversationThread and conversation on Microsoft Graph (v1.0 Reference)?"
- "Why and in which circumstances I'd be using group//threads over group//conversations anyway?"

In terms of group conversation feature design, as you probably have read, a post is always a part of some thread and that thread part of some conversation. In terms of API support, the API provides "parity" between conversation and thread - the convenience of not requiring you to always reference the parent conversation for a post. Just to be clear, that doesn't mean you can have a post or thread without a parent conversation; you just don't necessarily have to reference the parent conversation every time you access an existing thread or post. I'll start with creating a post: 
If you want to start posting to a new conversation, there are a few ways to do it, for your convenience:

(a) You can first [create a conversation](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_conversations) (POST /groups//conversations). You would specify a new thread and post in the request body. A successful query would create that new conversation, thread and post.

(b) Or, you can [create a thread without referencing any existing conversation](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_threads) (POST /groups//threads). You would specify the new thread and post in the request body. A successful query would create a new conversation containing that new thread and post.

After a post is created, you can use its ID to get, reply, forward, create or access attachments for that post by specifying both the parent conversation and thread, or just by specifying the parent thread. This is the so-called conversation and thread parity.

- "Here I assume that same subject means under the umbrella of that conversation?"

Yes, a conversation, its threads and posts all share the same subject. I think "subject" here is represented by the topic property.

- "if conversationThread is a collection of posts, that's pretty much the same of what conversation offers?"

What pulls threads and posts together under a conversation is the "subject". Think of it in the end user scenario - once a person on a conversation changes the subject, that person starts a new conversation.
In a conversation, sometimes a participant can spin off a side thread with a subset of the original participants. That constitutes a new "thread", as the subject has remained the same, just fewer participants.
Such is the feature design difference between conversations and threads. In terms of API functionality, you can reply to a thread (or post) and reference the parent thread, but you cannot reply by just referencing the parent conversation.

- "have also attempted creating a new post within the newly created thread"

I suspect you did a POST to an existing thread to try to create a post?

If that's the case, I'd like to point out that you cannot use POST to create a new group post. You can get a post created in one of the following ways:
- When creating a new conversation (POST /groups//conversations)
- When creating a new thread (POST /groups//threads)
- When replying to a thread 
- When replying to a post

Hope that helps.

Angelgolfer-ms

Comment: Hi @Angelgolfer-ms, that is an amazing explanation. Thank you very much for taking your time to share your knowledge! I feel I need time to digest the information, but it's much more clearer now.