# Office 365 Group Conversations - new thread always creates new conversation

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405567/whats-the-difference-between-conversationthread-and-conversation/35639488#35639488) explains the difference between conversations and conversationThreads in Office 365 Groups.

However it doesn't address the point made in the **EDIT**, namely that creating a new thread through the Graph API always creates a *new conversation*, rather than a *new thread in the existing conversation*, as [the documentation](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/conversation_post_threads) seems to suggest.

Is it possible to create multiple threads in the same conversation, either:

- Through the Office 365 UI
- Or through the Graph API?

Does anyone have examples of each?

To illustrate my problem - I have one conversation in my group:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c/conversations

Status Code: 200
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c')/conversations",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To=",
            "topic": "Conversation 1",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "lastDeliveredDateTime": "2017-02-24T14:03:57Z",
            "uniqueSenders": [
                "Peter Reay"
            ],
            "preview": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

It has one thread:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c/conversations/AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To=/threads

Status Code: 200
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c')/conversations('AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To%3D')/threads",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAMkABAA3aztzNtzdUaceiIjaUbZOhAA3aztzNtzdUaceiIjaUbZOg==",
            "topic": "Conversation 1",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "lastDeliveredDateTime": "2017-02-24T14:03:57Z",
            "uniqueSenders": [
                "Peter Reay"
            ],
            "preview": "...",
            "isLocked": false
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I try to create a new thread:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c/conversations/AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To=/threads

{
  "topic": "topic-value-2",
  "posts": [{
      "body": {
          "contentType": "html",
          "content": "Topic 2 Post 1"
      }
  }]
}

Status Code: 201
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c')/conversations('AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To%3D')/threads/$entity",
    "id": "AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAMkABAAn4DeT-lo0kS-qbfmsKjLZxAAn4DeT-lo0kS-qbfmsKjLZw=="
}
```

However, I try to get the threads, see the conversation still has just one thread:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c/conversations/AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To=/threads

Status Code: 200
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c')/conversations('AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To%3D')/threads",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c/conversations/AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To=/threads?$skip=1",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAMkABAA3aztzNtzdUaceiIjaUbZOhAA3aztzNtzdUaceiIjaUbZOg==",
            "topic": "Conversation 1",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "lastDeliveredDateTime": "2017-02-24T14:03:57Z",
            "uniqueSenders": [
                "Peter Reay"
            ],
            "preview": "...",
            "isLocked": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And we see, if I retrieve the conversations again, there is a new one:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c/conversations

Status Code: 200
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('41ea432e-441c-4394-8e5f-1914d3c9d41c')/conversations",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAJ_A3k-5aNJEv6m35rCoy2c=",
            "topic": "topic-value-2",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "lastDeliveredDateTime": "2017-02-24T14:12:44Z",
            "uniqueSenders": [
                "Peter Reay"
            ],
            "preview": "Topic 2 Post 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "AAQkADI2ZTIzMDBmLTUyZGMtNDM5My04ODhkLTVkMjY0Y2E2MjYyZAAQAN2s7czbc3VGnHoiI2lG2To=",
            "topic": "Conversation 1",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "lastDeliveredDateTime": "2017-02-24T14:03:57Z",
            "uniqueSenders": [
                "Peter Reay"
            ],
            "preview": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

I.e. a new *conversation* has been created, rather than a new *thread* in the existing conversation, which the documentation seems to suggest.

Can anyone explain this behaviour, and give an example of multiple threads in the same conversation?

Thanks